# Streaming tweets and store them on external drive: how to insert path file

Tags: python, twitter, path, tweepy

I will be streaming twitter data (mostly in arabic) for about 2 months using tweepy's Streamlistener and Python 3.6. I have a running code and I am almost ready to start the streaming.

Since the volume of the final file will be probably very large, I would like to store it on an external drive. Where and how can I add the path where to store it? (def init?)

Truly thankful for any suggestion and every advice!

Code (credit to Marco Bonzanini):

```
import sys 
import string 
import time
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream 
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
consumer_key = "xxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"
access_key = "xxx"
access_secret = "xxx"


class CustomListener(StreamListener): 


  def __init__(self, fname):
    safe_fname = format_filename(fname) 
    self.outfile = "stream_%s.jsonl" % safe_fname

  def on_data(self, data): 
    try: 
      with open(self.outfile, 'a') as f: 
        f.write(data) 
        return True 
    except BaseException as e: 
      sys.stderr.write("Error on_data: {}\n".format(e)) 
      time.sleep(5) 
    return True 

  def on_error(self, status): 
    if status == 420: 
      sys.stderr.write("Rate limit exceeded\n") 
      return False 
    else: 
      sys.stderr.write("Error {}\n".format(status)) 
      return True 

def format_filename(fname): 
"""Convert fname into a safe string for a file name. 

   Return: string 
  """ 
  return ''.join(convert_valid(one_char) for one_char in fname) 

 def convert_valid(one_char): 
  """Convert a character into '_' if "invalid". 

  Return: string 
  """ 
  valid_chars = "-_.%s%s" % (string.ascii_letters, string.digits) 
  if one_char in valid_chars: 
    return one_char 
  else: 
    return '_' 

 if __name__ == '__main__': 
  query = sys.argv[1:] # list of CLI arguments 
  query_fname = ' '.join(query) # string 
  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
  auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
  api = tweepy.API(auth)
  twitter_stream = Stream(auth, CustomListener(query_fname)) 
  twitter_stream.filter(track=query, async=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I think I can understand what you are asking for. In your code snippet, your file name is generated by the command line input (`sys.argv`, which are also the track keywords of twitter stream), but the path of the output file is unknown and you want to save the file into an external file path.

Here are three different options to solve your problem:

- Change working directory before running the script.
- Use fixed file path.
- Use dynamic file path by improving CLI parsing.

If the code is perfect, you can run the script in the working directory where you want to save the output file e.g., `cd /User/xxx/`. Then the output file will be put into the working directory. (Actually, your code is not so perfect, you may need to change the way you use the file--please use file pointer to avoid open file again and again.)

If the code is only used by yourself, then you can set fixed file path. A good coding pattern is that you prepare the file (both file path and file name) in the `__main__` entry and use it all the way through your other functions. Here is the code snippet.

```
# In class CustomListener, which use the file
def __init__(self, fname):
    # fname should be the actual file to write
    # e.g., /User/xxx/stream_tweets.json.txt
    try:
        self.fp = open(fname, 'w')
    except Exception:
        raise
...

# __main__ entry, prepare the file
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    query = sys.argv[1:] # list of CLI arguments 
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    # Preprocessing file name
    query_fname = ' '.join(query) # string
    query_fname = format_filename(query_fname) 
    query_fname = "stream_%s.jsonl" % query_fname
    query_fname = '/User/xxxx/' + query_fname
    twitter_stream = Stream(auth, CustomListener(query_fname))
```

In the `__main__` entry, you do some preprocessing to get the actual file name and concatenate it with the file path. And in `__init__`, you open the file and keep the file pointer, so that you do not need to open the file again and again in the future, especially for the `on_data` function, which writes lots of tweets.

If you want to specify the file path in the command line interface, you need to define a schema to parse the interface.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. I'm not sure, however, I understood you correctly. Say my file path is "/Users/jul/Desktop/Random", at which fname would I insert it? Sorry, I'm somewhat a complete newbie.

Comment: First of all thanks for the update. When I run the code as above (changing query_fname = with the actual file path) I get the following error: File "twitter_streaming_copy.py", line 73, in <module>
    twitter_stream = Stream(auth, CustomListener(query_fname)) 
  File "twitter_streaming_copy.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.fp = open(fname, 'w')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: (...). I reckon it must be sth very obvious..?

Comment: Does the parent directory of your saved file exist? When using `open` with `w` mode,  python will try to create the file. However, if the parent directories of this file do not exist, then `FileNotFoundError would be raised.